# How to check if users visiting the site are on root page or any other page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, request

Basically I want a certain layout to be used when someone is visiting the root page:

```
www.foo.com
```

And another layout when visiting anywhere else:

```
www.foo.com/asdf
```

I *could* use different _Layout files, but since the only change is here, I find that counterproductive.

Here's what I have tried, hopefully it illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() == "some way to check root?")
{
    @RenderBody()
}   
else
{
    <div id="big-kahuna"> <!-- Literally the only change. -->
        @RenderBody()    
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
if(Request.Url.PathAndQuery == "/") // root;
```

Comment: This fails if your app is running under a virtual directory. In that case Request.Url.PathAndQuery returns "/[virtual dir]/", so you will want if (Request.Url.PathAndQuery == @Url.Content("~"))

Comment: that wouldn't be the root of the site, it'd be the ***root of your app***. in your scenario you'd check for `/[virtual dir]` as the root of your virtual app.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath == "~/")
```